# Income , Outcome, And TOTAL

Tags: excel

[image: i have made table in excel like this]

there is a column which has name INCOME , OUTCOME and TOTAL 
i want to make TOTAL column as sum of INCOME COLUMN
EXAMPLE : if i enter data 50 in INCOME , i will get the value of 50
          and after that i enter new data again in INCOME let we say 40 
          so automatically 50 + 40 = 90 so the data in TOTAL will update to 90
          and so on if i enter new data in INCOME t will increase the data of 
          TOTAL
FOR  OUTCOME column , If i enter data in Outocome column so it will decrease the TOTAL COLUMN DATA

LET SAY THE TOTAL NOW IS 900
IF i enter data 200 in outcome the total will be 700
after that i enter new data again in outcome 300 so the total will be 400

Comment: You may give a picture of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula.

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUM(B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: `=SUM(A:A)` will sum all of your income. `=SUM(B:B)` will sum all of your outcome. Whole formula `=SUM(A:A)-SUM(B:B)` will minus from all income to all outcome, then it will show your total.